# is there a way to detect when user navigates to other componenet in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-material

So I want to show a confirmation popup when user tries t navigate to other page.
I read about hostListner and canActivate ...But I'm not getting any idea where to start!

please help !!TIA.

Comment: when you want to show this popup , when user navigate anywhere inside your app or you only want to show popup when user navigate out of your application?

Comment: anywhere inside the application !! @Dewanshu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to create a guard for routing
create a file named can-exit.guard.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanDeactivate} from '@angular/router';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

export interface CanExit {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanExitGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanExit> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanExit) {
    if (component.canDeactivate) {
      return component.canDeactivate();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

create another file
canExit.ts – This file is used to return the promised value.

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

export interface CanExit {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

After you add the above files in your application configure the router file as follows

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'your Path name',
    component: YourComponent ,
    canDeactivate: [CanExitGuard],
  }
];
// use this configuration in every path  of your application
```

Your component file needs some changes include canactivate in your component

```js
import { CanExit } from './../can-exit.guard';  //important


@Component({
  // your selector and component defs
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, CanExit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  canDeactivate(): Promise<any> | boolean {
    const confirmResult = confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page ? ');
    if (confirmResult === true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

hope this will help

Comment: thanks for help i was trying to do the same thing and you explained it very well

Comment: I tried its throwing error TypeError: Cannot read property 'canDeactivate' of null !! @Dewanshu

Comment: Please check your route, and make sure, that you have set the component property. can you share your code

Comment: @User209831 did u try this ?? is it working fine for u ?

Comment: `canDeactivate(MobilityStepComponent: CanExit) {
   
 if (MobilityStepComponent.canDeactivate) 
{
      return MobilityStepComponent.canDeactivate();
    }
    return true;
  }`

Here I'm getting MobilityStepComponent as null

Comment: @Dewanshu rest everything I replicated the same !

Comment: are you reaching till popup or this error is coming before that

Comment: popup is also not coming !! this problem is cause I've lazy loading implemented in my application!

Comment: Ok i find this problem i think its exactly what you are doing please have alook and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450323/typeerror-cannot-read-property-candeactivate-of-null

Comment: @Dewanshu Even I tried the same its working fine !! thank you so much

Comment: so for lazy loading we should add canDeactivate: [CanExitGuard]  to lazy route path.

`const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: MobilityStepComponent,canDeactivate: [CanExitGuard] },
];
`